# How make an embedded javascript widget based on underscore, backbone and jquery?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, widget

I want to do a web widget which will be embedded in my client website with a JS snippet like the one for google analytics.

My widget will add new functionality to the client website. I don't want to be in conflict with libraries used by my client website.

I found some resources to do a widget based only on JQuery like this one: http://www.stefanwienert.net/blog/2013/10/15/intro-on-making-a-javascript-widget/.

But I have not found guide to do the same thing with a underscore, backbone, jquery stack. How can I do the same thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any progress with this? I ran into the same issue...

Comment: I have done my widget with minified.js and in pure javascript. If it can help you...

Comment: @Frank can you share the steps you took? My original pages relies on external js libraries (such as EasyPieCharts), is it possible to utilize them in "widget mode" as well?